# Could the indeterminate form limit $\lim_{x\to a} [\frac{x^m-a^m}{x^n-a^n}]=\frac{m}{n}a^{m-n}$ be extended to all real numbers?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

In my text book I found that:

> $$\lim_{x\to a} \left[\frac{x^m-a^m}{x^n-a^n}\right]=\frac{m}{n}a^{m-n}$$
>   where $m$ and $n$ are any positive integers.

But could this be extended to any real number including $\ln{5}$ for example ?

Comment: Sure, let $x^n = u$ and you may interpret the limit as the derivative of $f(u)=u^{m/n}$ at  $u = a^n$. Recall that the power rule for derivative works for all real numbers...

Comment: It is much easier to prove that $(x^{n} - a^{n})/(x - a) \to na^{n - 1}$ as $x \to a$ for all all real $n$ such that $x^{n}$ is defined in a neighborhood of $x = a$ and the expression $na^{n - 1}$ is defined. This is easily established for positive integers (here given in your text book) and can be extended first to negative integers and then to rational $n$. These extensions are straightforward and almost algebraic in nature. For real $n$ use the definition $x^{n} = e^{n\log x}$.